# Exit program and open file

Tags: ruby

Hello I am stuck in a situation where I need to run a command after my program exits.

Reason :

MyApp1.exe needs to be updated to a new version MyApp2.exe. So, MyApp1.exe should be terminated before I start MyApp2.exe, else inno setup will not let me install the new version as the old version is still running.

```
File.open("MyApp2.exe", "wb") do |saved_file| 
open("http://example.com/MyApp2.exe", "rb") do |read_file| 
      saved_file.write(read_file.read) 
    end
  end
  `start "" "MyApp2.exe"`
  exit
```

Now the `start` command is before exit, as I want to start the new downloaded MyApp2.exe, but I would like to exit first and then start the installer.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be achieved using [Kernel::exec](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-exec) instead of backticks or the `system` method. Unlike other shell-invoking commands, `exec` replaces the currently running process (i.e. the Ruby interpreter) with the new process.

Your whole script would then be

```
  File.open("MyApp2.exe", "wb") do |saved_file| 
    open("http://example.com/MyApp2.exe", "rb") do |read_file| 
      saved_file.write(read_file.read) 
    end
  end
  exec 'start "" "MyApp2.exe"'
```

You cannot continue with any statements following `exec`, the program will exit at that point.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: No I am not 100% certain. I have only ever used it on Mac and Linux, I don't have Windows machine available to test.

Comment: The doc specifically mentions windows, so I guess it will work.